# If P is a closed perfect subset of a separable complete metric space M, then each point of P is a condensation point of P.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*, first edition, p. 131, problem 108:

> Let $P$ be a closed perfect subset of a separable complete metric space $M$. Prove that each point of $P$ is a condensation point of $P$.

I think I can prove this, but I never use the hypothesis that $M$ is separable, so I wonder if I've done something wrong. Here is my attempt:

**Proposition.** If $P$ is a closed perfect subset of a complete metric space $M$, then each point of $P$ is a condensation point of $P$.

**Proof.** Suppose not, so we have some point $p \in P$ which is not a condensation point of $P$, and thus has a countable neighborhood $P_r p$ of radius $r > 0$. Since there are only countably many points in this neighborhood, there must be some real radius $s \in (0, r]$ such that no points in $P$ are distance $s$ from $p$, and thus $P_s p$ has empty boundary in $P$ and is therefore clopen in $P$.

An open subset of a perfect set is perfect, so $P_s p \subseteq P$ is perfect. A closed subset of a complete set is complete, so $P_s p \subseteq P \subseteq M$ is complete. $P_s p$ is non-empty (since it contains $p$), perfect, and complete, so by Theorem 58 it is uncountable. However, $P_s p$ is a subset of $P_r p$, so this implies that $P_r p$ is uncountable, a contradiction. $\Box$

Have I made some mistake? Thanks very much.

Comment: What is a "condensation point"?

Comment: A point p of S is a condensation point if every neighborhood of p in S contains uncountably many points.

Comment: Your proof would be self-contained except for "Theorem 58"; other than that it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks! The proof of theorem 58 uses diagonalization to produce a Cauchy sequence converging to a point not on the proposed enumeration.

Comment: So that makes me suspicious. Construction of a sequence might make use of a countable basis. The question is: What hypothesis does Theorem 58 require?

Comment: Theorem 58 is that any non-empty, perfect, complete metric space $M$ is uncountable. It makes no assumption of separability (countable base). The proof is by contradiction: assume it's countable so that there's an enumeration $(x_n)$ of points in $M$. Starting with $x_1$, perfectness gives us some other point $p_1$ in a neighborhood of it.

Comment: (contd.) We can then choose a neighborhood of $p_1$ small enough to exclude $x_1$ and by perfectness there still must be another point inside it other than $x_2$ which we call $p_2$. Proceeding this way, we can ensure that the diameters of these neighborhoods go to zero while also excluding each $x_k$ for $k$ between $1$ and $n$. The resulting sequence $(p_n)$ is Cauchy so by completeness converges to some point not in our enumeration.

Comment: Seems pretty clear then. I cannot see anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help!