# Is every point in a perfect set necessarily a condensation point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Wikipedia definition: A condensation point $p$ of a subset $S$ of a topological space, is any point $p$, such that every open neighbourhood of $p$ contains uncountably many points of $S$. Thus, "condensation point" is synonymous with $\aleph _{1}$-accumulation point".

My question is: *is it true that in any given perfect set, every point is a condensation point?* Let's please stick with asking this question in just $\mathbb{R}$ for starters, unless a more general proof/counterexample is just as easy to understand.

As for the question, I'm not sure (obviously). By definition, a perfect set $P$ has the property: every point of $P$ is a limit point of $P$. But that doesn't immediately imply that every point is a condensation point. But also, constructing a counter-example seems hard.

If we start with Cantor set and either add or remove sets of points, with the goal of creating a new set which is perfect but contains at least one non-condensation point, then ??? I'm not sure but this seems difficult to control and envisage what's going on.

I mean, I'm assuming that every member of the Cantor set is a condensation point. Is this correct?

I suspect the answer to the question is "yes".

Perhaps the answer to the question is covered when answering Rudin's PMA Exercise from Chapter 2 Q27, which I have not yet done.

My attempt, which is to :

Suppose $P \subset \mathbb{R}$ is perfect, and let $p \in P$ be a point that is $not$ a condensation point of $P$. Then $\exists$ a neighbourhood of $p$ which contains countably many points of $P$ (it cannot be just a finite number of points, since then $p$ would not be a limit point of $P$, so would not be perfect, a contradition). I'm not sure where to go from here.

I also feel like I'm missing something obvious.

By the way, the converse, "A set where every point is a condensation point, is perfect", is obviously false: just consider (0,1) or any open set in R. However, what if we modify this slightly: "A closed set where every point is a condensation point, is perfect". I wonder if this is true?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set

Comment: I have, obviously. I don't see how it addresses my question. There's nothing on there about condensation points.

Comment: You may want to know that all compact perfect subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic to a finite union of closed intervals and Cantor sets. As for the fact that all the points of the Cantor set are condensation points you are correct: it is actually easy if you know that the Cantor set has continuum cardinality and every point has a left or right semi-neighbrhood that is homeomorphic to the Cantor set itself. Note that outside of $\mathbb{R}$ your claim on condensation point may be false: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The characterization of compact perfect subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ should follow from the fact that every compact perfect metrizable and totally disconnected space is isomorphic to the Cantor set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space

Comment: @Dunnò000 wow, that's interesting, and a revelation! So the answer to the original question is "yes". What about my question right at the end: "A closed set where every point is a condensation point, is perfect". Is this also true? I think from your last comment the answer is also "yes", but I just want to make sure.

Comment: From the wiki reference: "Cantor also showed that every non-empty perfect subset of the real line has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$."  If $a$ is a point in a perfect set $P$ in $\mathbb R$ , then $P \cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is a nonempty perfect subset of $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$.  Also, $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$

Comment: Yes GEdgar, I already knew that perfect sets are uncountable. Again, I don't see how that's helpful in answering my question though.

Comment: Here's one approach, which can be made rigorous in various ways: Let $C$ be a Cantor set in $\mathbb R$ (doesn't have to be the middle thirds Cantor set). Pick $x \in C$ and let $I$ be an open interval containing $x.$ Then because the complement of $C$ is consists of a "densely arranged" collection of open intervals and $x \in I,$ it follows that there exists a sequence $\{I_n\}$ of these open intervals that converges to $x.$ Let $J$ and $J'$ be two of these that lie within $I.$ Then $C$ intersect the closed interval lying between $J$ and $J'$ is also a Cantor set (needs a bit of proof).

Comment: Incidentally, although what I said is correct, namely that $C$ intersect the closed interval lying between $J$ and $J'$ is a Cantor set, you don't want to get too hung up on this exact result. All you need is the existence of continuum many points of $C$ in the interval $I,$ so think about how the fact that a finitely branching tree with countable infinitely many nodes (or something along these lines) has continuum many paths tells you that there will be continuum many points of $C$ between $J$ and $J'.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675423/52912

Comment: At the bottom of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorSet.html it says: “*The* Cantor set is the only totally disconnected, perfect, compact metric space up to a homeomorphism (Willard 1970) “. I guess it means the Ternary Cantor Set. The preceding line says that, for example, [0,1], and ( [5,6] united with the Ternary Cantor set ) are “general Cantor set”. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: "You may want to know that all compact perfect subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic to a finite union of closed intervals and Cantor sets." Surely it's countably infinite union, not just finite union?

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space, and $A$ is perfect and $x \in A$ it follows that for any $r>0$, $D(x,r) \cap A$ is non-empty (where $D(x,r) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) \le r\}$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x$).

$D(x,r)$  is closed and hence so is $D(x,r) \cap A$ and thus also complete.

So if $D(x,r) \cap A$ were countable for some $r>0$, we must have an isolated point $a_0 \in D(x,r) \cap A$ (or we'd contradict the Baire property) and this can only happen if $A$ already had an isolated point, which is not the case. So all points of $A$ are condensation points.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. However, I'm not familiar with the Baire property, Baire spaces, sigma-algebras and so on. I have much to learn. I'll probably have to come back to this question later on.

Comment: @AdamRubinson for $\Bbb R$ you could give an additional hoc argument too, as long as you know Cantor’s intersection theorem e.g.  it’s just convenient to rely on general theorems.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I edited back.

Comment: @AdamRubinson if $x$ is a limit point of $A$, $D(x,A) \cap A$ is infinite for all $r$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson it *is* true. A closed subset of a complete space is complete.

Comment: "So if $D(x,r) \cap A$ were countable for some $r>0$, we must have an isolated point $a_0 \in D(x,r) \cap A$ (or we'd contradict the Baire property)" What is the justification for this? You've merely asserted it, but I don't see how it follows in your argument.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing my question right at the end: "If a closed set has the property: every point is a condensation point. Is it perfect?"

The answer is obviously yes.

It's closed. And every point is a condensation point and is therefore a limit point, so the set fits the definition of a perfect set.